# React with websocket child component performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have created a React application which has ws.onmessage in  componentDidMount(). I am parsing the JSON coming back from the WebSocket (every 2 seconds), setting the state and it renders in the child component fine. The only problem is that the JSON.Parse() is taking some time, so scrolling and selecting rows in the child component's grid (ag-grid) is not as smooth as it should be. Is there any way to improve that performance? Can it be make asynchronous? Can I separate the onmessage from the component?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Maybe try using promises and lazy loading so that your UI stays responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

> Is there any way to improve that performance? Can it be make
>   asynchronous? Can I separate the onmessage from the component?

That is a broad question. Maybe check out the [guid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to properly compose questions so that we can help you.

As to your problem:

Check out [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/) about lazy loading. This can work for all kinds of content or component. Just have a temporary simple component or anything replace it. It is asynchronous by nature.

You can separate your events by having them be [asynchronous](https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/asynchronous-rendering-with-react-c323cda68f41) so that the UI can keep working and be as responsive as possible.

Hope this helps.